# JMeter: "Object Moved" displayed in Response Data

Tags: soap, jmeter

I am trying to load test a Web Service using SOAP/XML RPC Request,
however, below Response data I receive:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Error/NotFound">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

What might have gone wrong.

Please refer below Screenshot for Response Data and SOAP/XML-RPC Request details:
https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/1.png/_4c8624828477427ca895b4de7c568ac5

https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/2.png/_06bdb3d9af764353a41e12fb5272b043

Comment: Is the functionality working fine via browser or otherwise ??

Comment: Yes, Manually it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Use "**HTTP Sampler**" instead of "**SOAP/XML RPC**" with content type as "application/xml" in header manager.

Paste the web-service XML in "***Body Data***" & keep method as "**POST**" of "*HTTP Sampler*".

Also click on "follow redirects" in "*HTTP Sampler*"

Hope this will help.